# How to convert the time zone to local?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I get dates on the site for some events:

```py
>>> parse(event.find_element_by_xpath('../td[@data-dt]').get_attribute('data-dt'))
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 26, 19, 15, tzinfo=<StaticTzInfo 'Z'>)
```

How can I convert this time to a local time zone, so that I can count down to the start of the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```py
from tzlocal import get_localzone
parse(event.find_element_by_xpath('../td[@data-dt]').get_attribute('data-dt')).astimezone(get_localzone())
```